# Can I create a "simple" Cyclic Redundancy Check program in Python?

Tags: python, crc, redundancy, directory-listing, cyclic

I am quite green in the ways of Python programming and was tasked with creating a simple program that ran a CRC check. Can anyone suggest a good start point on which modules to use/read up on?  I suppose a simple program would just be doing a CRC on binary code generated in Python, and not on actual executables.

Another task I have is to list a directory structure.  I have found the OS module, I take it that the OS module is the right place to look for all things directories?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to calculate the CRC, its already part of the [binascii](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html) module. There is also a short example to help to get started.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pycrc](http://www.tty1.net/pycrc/index_en.html) to do standard CRCs

Comment: Update: I have found an interesting site that attempts to simplify the explanation of CRC - http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt